# Is it better to store an array of values in a table field or define a child table to store each value of the array?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I was wondering because I feel is not the best way of storing array values in a table field. I have seen people serializes array and to retrive data unserializes, some other use csv. I don't know but I do not feel comfortable doing it this way. I was wondering if this is a valid practice or what is the best way of doing it.
I also think that the problem comes when you want to edit values from a child table that contains each field and value, how can you know if data is already inserted and realated to the parent table, how to know if you need to add or update that single values?

Comment: A normalized design is often the best way to go.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: The very 1st Normal Form is, to have Only One values in a Column and A column should store only one value. This is the least you should do with any RDBMS. store each element of the array to a separate row and create a column which contains the array/List ID for all the related array elements in a table. Will make your SELECT, UPDATE and DELETE operations fairly simple and more performance efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always contextual.  If you're just asking an abstract question then generally you would add a child table for all the usual reasons you normalize.

But, it might be the way to go if you have a situation where you will never update the array, you would always want to select the entire array, you would never filter on any member or combination of members in the array, there are no attributes that describe any single member of the array, you have extremely high velocity...you get the idea.  So maybe for a log.  But you might consider writing a log to something other than a relational database table.